# Built-in way to determine whether a string is a Ruby reserved word?

Tags: ruby, string, keyword, reserved-words, built-in

Is there something built-in with Ruby to determine if a string is a reserved word? Something like `"next".is_keyword?`?

Comment: Checking for Ruby's reserved words is probably not going to help much if you're worried about stomping on a method or class name. Gems and modules can add all sorts of new words that have significance in their context that won't show up in a check for Ruby's reserved word list. So, you might identify a few words, but miss the huge majority added by the standard library and any other core modules plus gems you've loaded.

Comment: The context is Ruby test objects and code generation, based on database table and column names, and other Ruby code. Need to make sure that no table or column names are Ruby keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is loading an array with all the keywords you know about.

```ruby
class String
  def is_keyword?
    %w{__FILE__ __LINE__ alias and begin BEGIN break case class def defined? do else elsif end END ensure false for if in module next nil not or redo rescue retry return self super then true undef unless until when while yield}.include? self
  end
end
"foobar".is_keyword? # => false
"for".is_keyword? # => true
```

For reference:

- I *know* this isn't a built-in way, it's just the only way I could think of. Don't downvote me for it.
- The list I included is that of true keywords. `public`, `protected` and friends aren't really keywords, just the names of important methods which are called during the creation of modules or classes. You can think of it as elements of the Ruby DSL.

Comment: I am actually doing this now, as it seems there isn't a built-in way

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `protected` isn't really a reserved word. It's just the name of an important method.

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords lists reserved words you can't use (some of them only apply if you're using Rails or its dependencies), and method names that can cause problems.

If this doesn't fully answer your question, can you define more fully whether you're interested in method names or variable names, and whether you're worried about words that can't be used at all, or words that may cause other things to go wrong?

Comment: A Ruby-specific list of reserved words can be found [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#S3).

Comment: The Rails reserved words list is pretty huge, and some of those words are just the names of commonly used classes like `Struct`. I advise not to use that list.

Comment: @Kudu: You probably wouldn't want a method name called `Struct` anyway, considering that it's fairly un-idiomatic. Also, I don't think the downvote on this answer was justified, considering that the question being answered is fairly vague.

Comment: On vague questions, I tend to think that most answers shouldn't be downvoted, and that any decent effort to reply deserves an upvote.

Comment: You're right. `protected` isn't actually a keyword. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ruby gem [rubykeyword](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubykeyword). It does more than identifying the keyword. `string.keyword?` tells you if its keyword or not. `string.define` gives a definition  of the keyword. There is `string.example` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class where you want to implement a method called "protected", then before you define that method make an instance of that class and call

> instance.methods

This will show you all the methods inherited for the class, and if "protected" is there then it is reserved by ruby.

Comment: The question isn't about methods in superclasses, it's about determining what's a keyword.